# Conexão encerra ao enviar uma mensagem do cliente para o servidor (c/c++ socket)

Tags: c, c++, socket, socket.io

Estou usando os códigos abaixo para fazer um conexão cliente-servidor. O cliente eu mesmo estou fazendo e o servidor por enquanto peguei na internet. A conexão entre eles é feita e o servidor manda uma mensagem, o cliente recebe a mensagem e imprime no terminal, mas quando tento enviar uma mensagem do cliente para o servidor os dois encerram a conexão.

Class do cliente:

```
#ifndef socket_hpp
#define socket_hpp 
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

namespace Socket {
    class Exception {
    private:
        std::string _message;
    public:
        Exception(std::string error) { this->_message = error; }
        virtual const char* what() { return this->_message.c_str(); }
    };

    class TCP_IPV4 {
    private:
        int port;
        std::string address;
        int buffer_len;
        char *buffer;
        bool binded;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        int socketfd;

    public:
        TCP_IPV4(int port, std::string address, int buffer_len);
        ~TCP_IPV4();
        char* getMessage();
        int _connect ();
        int _recv(char* message);
        void _send(char* message);
        void _close();
        int _bind();
    };

    TCP_IPV4::TCP_IPV4(int port, std::string address, int buffer_len) {
        if ((socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
            throw Exception("[Constructor] Cannot create socket");

        this->port = port; 
        this->address = address;
        this->buffer_len = buffer_len;
        buffer = new char[buffer_len];
        binded = false;

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(port);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address.c_str());
        memset(server.sin_zero, 0x0, 8);
    }

    TCP_IPV4::TCP_IPV4::~TCP_IPV4() {
        delete buffer;
    }

    int TCP_IPV4::_connect() {
        int connection = connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
        if (connection == -1)
            throw Exception("[Connect] Cannot connect socket");

        return connection;
    }

    int TCP_IPV4::_recv(char* message) {
        memset(buffer, 0x0, buffer_len);
        int len = recv(socketfd, buffer, buffer_len, 0);
        buffer[len + 1] = '\0';
        strcpy(message, buffer);
        return len;
    }

    void TCP_IPV4::_send(char* message) {
        send(socketfd, message, strlen(message), 0);
    }

    void TCP_IPV4::_close() { 
        close(socketfd);
    }
}

#endif
```

E esta parte usa o cliente que estou fazendo:

```
#include "./socket.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    try {
        Socket::TCP_IPV4 socket(4242, "127.0.0.1", 4242);

        socket._connect();

        char message[4242];

        while(1) {
            cout << "message: ";
            cin >> message;

            if(strcmp(message, "exit"))
                break;
            socket._send(message);
            cout << "message has been sended" << endl;
            socket._recv(message);
            cout << "_recv message: " << message << endl;
        }
    }
    catch(Socket::Exception &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Servidor que peguei na internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>


/* Server port  */
#define PORT 4242


/* Buffer length */
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 4096



/*
 * Main execution of the server program of the simple protocol
 */
int
main(void) {

    /* Client and Server socket structures */
    struct sockaddr_in client, server;

    /* File descriptors of client and server */
    int serverfd, clientfd;

    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];

    fprintf(stdout, "Starting server\n");

    /* Creates a IPv4 socket */
    serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverfd == -1) {
        perror("Can't create the server socket:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Server socket created with fd: %d\n", serverfd);


    /* Defines the server socket properties */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    memset(server.sin_zero, 0x0, 8);


    /* Handle the error of the port already in use */
    int yes = 1;
    if(setsockopt(serverfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                  &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket options error:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /* bind the socket to a port */
    if(bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1 ) {
        perror("Socket bind error:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /* Starts to wait connections from clients */
    if(listen(serverfd, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Listen error:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Listening on port %d\n", PORT);

    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
    if ((clientfd=accept(serverfd,
        (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len )) == -1) {
        perror("Accept error:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /* Copies into buffer our welcome messaage */
    strcpy(buffer, "Hello, client!\n\0");


    /* Sends the message to the client */
    if (send(clientfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Client connected.\nWaiting for client message ...\n");

        /* Communicates with the client until bye message come */
        do {

            /* Zeroing buffers */
            memset(buffer, 0x0, BUFFER_LENGTH);

            /* Receives client message */
            int message_len;
            if((message_len = recv(clientfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0)) > 0) {
                buffer[message_len - 1] = '\0';
                printf("Client says: %s\n", buffer);
            }


            /* 'bye' message finishes the connection */
            if(strcmp(buffer, "bye") == 0) {
                send(clientfd, "bye", 3, 0);
            } else {
                send(clientfd, "yep\n", 4, 0);
            }

        } while(strcmp(buffer, "bye"));
    }

    /* Client connection Close */
    close(clientfd);

    /* Close the local socket */
    close(serverfd);

    printf("Connection closed\n\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: numa olhada superficial parece que o código funciona, mas primeira coisa a fazer é colocar tratamento de erro de no receive e no send para saber o que REALMENTE está acontecendo

Comment: Meu resolveu isso?

Comment: Não lembro se resolvi isso, já faz um tempo. Mas se tiver interesse no código ele está aqui https://gitlab.com/emanuelxavier1999/cplusplus_socket